# Django and Subprocess: Development Server is Terminated on signal.SIGTERM

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.Popen` in a Django application. I then store the `pid` in a database. The user can then send a rest request to `/api/task/task.id/stop/` in order to kill the task.

This all works fine, except that when I kill the subprocess the Django development server is also terminated. How do I go about killing the subprocess without killing the dev server?

I start my process like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["nohup {} {} {}".format(settings.PYTHON, "task.py", task.id) ], shell=True )

task.pid = process.pid

task.save()
```

And I am terminating it like this:

```
os.killpg( os.getpgid(task.pid), signal.SIGTERM )
```

Comment: use celery for async tasks

Comment: Is it not possible to do it like I am attempting? I have looked into celery but my aim is to distribute this bundled as part of an Electron application - so I would like to avoid celery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612 <- Answered here. I was missing the `preexec_fn=os.setsid`